# an issue with handler.postDelayed() method

Tags: java, android, handler, postdelayed

i'm using `handler.postDelayed()` method to repeat a task with time delay  .. this is my code ;

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,pickup+" "+destination+" "+ Boolean.toString(requested),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}, 5000);
```

the problem is with the variables (pickup,destination,requested) for example requested which is a `boolean`   i'm declaring it as false at the beggining and after that i'm setting it true in `oncreate()` .. and in the handler it's value changes every 5 seconds between true and false ( that's mean between the new and the old value ).. the the same thing with the other 2 variables .

this is my complete code:

```
String pickup="/",destination="/";
Boolean requested=false;
int seats=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {



            if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("class").equals("request")){
                pickup = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pickup");
                destination = getIntent().getExtras().getString("destination");
                seats = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("seats");


                if (!pickup.equals("")&&!pickup.equals("/")&&!destination.equals("")&&!destination.equals("/")&&seats!=0){


                    requested=true;

                }

            }
}

        if (authenticate() == true) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                public void run() {





                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,pickup+" "+destination+" "+ Boolean.toString(requested),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                }
            }, 5000); }}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code for that class?

Comment: ok i will add it in the main question .

Answer (score 0):

Not problem with handler.postDelayed(), Try it if you want switch value.
pickup = !pickup, destination = !destination, ...

Comment: i'm already  switching values for examble : " requested=true;" in oncreate(), and it shows true for 5 seconds and then it shows false .

Comment: I really dont understand your expectation. Please clear it again. your expectation is you want show true, false, true, false, ... or it Auto true false without your handle ?

Comment: my expectation is not to show : true, false, true, false, ...   that is problem it self ... my expectation is to set the values of the variables from a button for example and to send these changes with a handler

Comment: I think somewhere in class change these variable. Please check all of class.